# SQLite Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite

Estou tentando trabalhar com SQLite no Visual Studio 2008 para fazer um sistema para Windows Embedded Compact 7. O problema é que sempre dá o seguinte erro:

> ```
> A first chance exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll   
> Additional information: Can't find PInvoke DLL 'SQLite.Interop.066.DLL'.
> ```

Não importa o que eu faça, já baixei e testei várias DLL's. Eu consigo adicionar a DLL *System.Data.SQLite* como referência, mas ao tentar adicionar *SQLite.Interop.066.DLL* gera o seguinte error:

> ```
> A reference to 'SQLite.Interop.066.DLL' could not added.
> ```

Tentei também colocar as DLL's na pasta junto com o executável no emulador (Windows Embedded Compact 7) porém também sem sucesso.

Alguém já trabalhou com SQLite no VS 2008 poderia me ajudar por favor? Agreço  caso faça um passo a passo :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa Biblioteca `SQLite.Interop.066.DLL` é uma biblioteca para PInvoke, você não referencia a mesma e sim inclui ela para ser distribuída no diretório da sua aplicação.

Para incluir a mesma, coloque ela dentro do seu projeto:

1. Clique com o botão direito no seu projeto e vá em "Add" -> "Existing Item";
2. Selecione o arquivo `SQLite.Interop.066.DLL`;
3. Após incluído no projeto, clique com o botão direito em cima do arquivo e vá em "Properties";
4. Em "Build Action" selecione a opção "Compile";
5. Em "Copy to Output Directory" selecione a opção "Copy aways";

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Fiz os passos a seguir, mas o erro continua. Tentei também inserir manualmente no projeto para ver se iria reconhecer, mas sem sucesso.

Comment: @Noah, Eu verifiquei aqui, no meu projeto eu selecionei a opção "Compile" em "Build Action", tente isso, eu editei a pergunta

Comment: Borges ao colocar como Compile gera o erro "could not be opened", também tentei como Content e os restantes, mas também sem muito progresso. Acredito que eu esteja utilizando as DLL erradas. Agradeço pelo tempo que dispôs a me ajudar :)

Comment: @ Julio Borges , pode me informar qual a sua DLL ? se possível colocar um link para eu fazer download e testar aqui?

Comment: @Noah, eu ultilizo a System.Data.SQLite da phxsoftware https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki#sqlite-netFx35-binary-PocketPC-ARM-2008 na versão 1.0.66 ao que parece é a mesma que voce utiliza. no meu caso só tem uma diferença é que a biblioteca interop esta com o nome SQLite.Interop.DLL e não SQLite.Interop.066.DLL, tenta alterar o nome da dll e ve se funciona